# Java - JPanel won't show up on JFrame when overriding JFrame's paint

Tags: java, swing, graphics, awt, jframe

I have a JFrame on which I am using overriding the `paint` method to display some graphics. I also want to add a JPanel to it that will show up on top of the graphics. Right now, all I see is the graphics created from JFrame paint method.

Here's my JPanel:

```
public class NoteDraw extends JPanel {

    public NoteDraw() {
        setSize(200, 100);
        setBackground(Color.BLACK);
    }

    @Override public void paintComponent(Graphics g) {
        super.paintComponent(g);
        g.setColor(Color.red);
        g.fillRect(0, 0, 100, 100);
    }
}
```

Here's my JFrame:

```
public class ui extends JFrame {
    public void paint(Graphics g) {
        //do some drawing here...
    }
}
```

Here's my main:

```
public class Main {
    static ui main_gui = new ui();

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        NoteDraw note = new NoteDraw();
        main_gui.getContentPane().add(note);
        main_gui.setVisible(true);
    }
}
```

Comment: And before/after "//do some drawing here..." you of course have `super.paint(g);`, right?

Comment: No, I'm both mentally retarded and new to Java... what does super.paint(g); do anyways?

Comment: @tybro0103, it will invoke the base behavior (the normal behavior of the frame to paint its contents) -- much like you have `super.paintComponent(g);` in the panel.

Comment: Thanks, I'm still getting the same results though.

Comment: @tybro0103, given your example, you should probably put the `super.paint(g);` at the end of your method (after your own custom painting).  Does that change the complexion?

Comment: So if I understand correctly, super.paint will invoke the normal paint method as if it wasn't over-ridden, but also run my new turdy code?

Comment: when I put it at the end, the JPanel shows, but none of the JFrame graphics

Answer (score 1):

You should NEVER override the paint() method of a JFrame (unless you really know what you are doing). This method is responsible for all the optimized painting behaviour of Swing.

Custom painting should always be done by overriding the paintComponent() method of a Swing component like you have done on your NoteDraw panel.

The reason the code in the paint method doesn't show is because the NoteDraw panel is opaque and therefore the panel paints over top of the Graphics code in your paint method.

So the solution is to move the Graphics painting code to the NoteDraw panel.

Or if you are trying to create some kind of background image for your frame then you can try using the [Background Panel](http://tips4java.wordpress.com/2008/10/12/background-panel/).

Or if you truly do need custom painting then you create a background panel and override the paintComponent() method. Then you set the layout to a BorderLayout and add this panel to the frame. Then you make your NoteDraw panel non-opaque and add it to the custom background panel. Now the background will show through on the NoteDraw panel.

Answer (score -1):

Remember to call `super.paint()` when you override your `paint()` method.

This way, you still use the behavior defined in the parent class, and you can add your modifications safely.

---

**Resources :**

- [sun.com - Using the Keyword super](http://download.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/IandI/super.html)

Comment: Thanks, mentioned in a comment earlier, but that's not the problem.